# paper-button with type="submit" within form doesn't submit?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, paper-elements

I am trying to use `paper-button` with `type` attribute set to `submit` (as one would do with `button` element) to submit the enclosing `form`, but for some reason it is unable to submit the form. Is this a bug or feature?

How to make `paper-button` submit the form?

PS: I am in dart land (not js).

Comment: Filed as issue here: https://github.com/Polymer/paper-button/issues/14

Answer (score 7):

As noticed by Gunter, you can create a custom element which extends some of native element with your desired semantics.

I encountered with your issue too and I've created simple element which gives ability to submit to `paper-button`

```
<polymer-element name="paper-button-submit" extends="button" noscript>
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        border: 0;
        background: transparent;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: inherit;
      }
    </style>
    <paper-button>
      <content></content>
    </paper-button>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Then you can write this

```
<button type="submit" is="paper-button-submit">Add</button>
```

And will get a button with paper-like look

Comment: I use polymer on Javascript, but I believe that it can work in Dart too.

Comment: This works fine in Dart, and doesn't require any supporting dart code. I chose to call the component 'paper-native-button', because it doesn't actually define anything re. submit - that happens at point of use (which is more powerful). This seems a pretty elegant solution.

Comment: Actually, I found I did need to add some supporting script to pass through the button attributes like 'raised'. Gist with changes/additions: https://gist.github.com/hawkett/49146a43d8595aa6c468 - 3 things to note - remove the 'noscript' attribute (http://mobilemancer.com/2015/01/06/rookie-mistakes-developing-web-components-in-polymer/), made the font inheritance more complete and added script to support the 'raised' attribute.

Comment: I would love to pass attributes like `disabled`, `raised`, and `z` to the paper button. without the help of dart. If anyone gets there before me, please share!

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve the form submit by placing a native button inside the paper-button element:

```
<paper-button>
  <button>Sign Up</button>
</paper-button>
```

Then use this following CSS to hide the native button while ensuring it's hitzone fills the entire paper-button element:

```
<style shim-shadowdom>
  paper-button {
    padding:0;
  }
  paper-button::shadow .button-content {
    padding:0;
  }
  paper-button button {
    padding:1em;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  paper-button button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

There was already a discussion about using Polymer elements containing form elements within a form in the Polymer Google group and as far as I remember I answered a similar question here on SO (I will do some research afterwards).

1) You can extend an input element

```dart
<polymer-element name="my-element" extends="input">
   ...
</polymer-element>
```

and use it like

```dart
<input is="my-element">
```

2) You can do the form processing in custom code
(read the values from the form elements and create an AJAX call to send the data to the server)

3) Create a custom form element (extends the 2nd)
which does the form processing and AJAX call

The 1st option is not applicable to core-elments/paper-elements because the don't extend an `<input>` (or any other form element) but embed it.
This applies to form input elements and also to the form submit button.

#### Some more or less related topics

- [Polymer Google Group - polymer element as form input element](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/polymer-dev/form/polymer-dev/V0qah6T1Lzk/FjVfT44BAuIJ)
- [Getting HTML5 to work in Form with multiple polymer-dart components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115123)
- [Seth Ladd's Blog - Forms, HTTP servers, and Polymer with Dart](http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/09/forms-http-servers-and-polymer-with-dart.html)
- [Dart Polymer form field not showing validate errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309160)
- [How do you get HTML5 inputs to validate if they are inside Polymer Web Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615634)

What you can do if only the submit button is a Polymer element, is to invoke the `click()` method on an invisible (non-Polymer) submit button in the click handler of the `<paper-button>`
for more details see
- [Polymer: manually submitting a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151817)

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive list of options, but unfortunately, this still doesn't answer my original question. I will wait for some more time to see if there's any workaround to get native form to be submitted via paper-button.

Comment: There is nothing planned so far, could be you have a very long time to wait. I guess you just have to do the submit processing 'manually' similar as shown in Seth's blog post.

Comment: To be clear, a `paper-forms` project is already underway for Polymer JS.

Comment: @ScottMiles Great to hear! Didn't saw it mentioned somewhere yet.

Comment: Looks like the only way to easily submit these custom form fields is with [ajax-form](https://github.com/garstasio/ajax-form).  This is what the Polymer team recommends as well.  Disclaimer: I'm the author of ajax-form.

Comment: @ScottMiles Source on that?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to create a custom element. According to [the docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form) the following apporach is recommended:

```html
<paper-button raised onclick="submitForm()">Submit</paper-button>
```

```js
function submitForm() {
  document.getElementById('form').submit();
}
```

so you would just bind the `onclick` event to a function that manually submits your form.

**UPDATE**

Although the previous example from `iron-form` uses `onclick` event [it is recommended](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html) to use `on-tap` over `on-click`:

> Tip: Use `on-tap` rather than `on-click` for an event that fires
>   consistently across both touch (mobile) and click (desktop) devices.

It is also a good idea to use Polymers [own DOM API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#dom-api):

```js
function submitForm(e) {
  Polymer.dom(e).localTarget.parentElement.submit();
}
```