# How to submit a form with polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I've have this polymer contact-element:

```
<polymer-element name="contact-element">
  <template>
    <paper-input label="Your Name" id="contact-name" floatingLabel></paper-input>
    <paper-input multiline label="Your text here..." id="contact-message" floatingLabel></paper-input>
    <paper-button label="Send Data" id="contact-submit" raisedButton></paper-button>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({});
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

It's included in this index.html

```
<form action="/sendMessage" method="GET">
        <contact-element></contact-element>
</form>
```

Is there an submit-attribute for the paper-button or do I have to do the submit with JS?

Comment: As far as I know you still need to deal with sending forms like always. Isn't polymer just a custom tag and import library?

Comment: Yes, but polymer doesn't render a "real" button. It's only a CSS-styled DIV. So it's not possible to submit my form.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `<button type="submit">..</button>`?

Comment: I thought there is a way to use the paper-button elements. They are already styled with css.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867107/paper-button-with-type-submit-within-form-doesnt-submit

Answer (score 2):

Try the ajax-form element: http://ajax-form.raynicholus.com.

It supports the paper elements.

Answer (score 2):

For any future Readers, now that 1.0 is released:

This is basic html form processing. At the time of this writing, Polymer now has the [iron-form](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form), but you still submit it like any other form.

```
<form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/">

  <paper-input name="testinput"></paper-input>

  <paper-button raised click="document.getElementById('form').submit();">
     Post
  </paper-button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

From Polymer's blog:
https://blog.polymer-project.org/featured/2014/09/23/featured-002/

Ray Nicholus’ ajax-form element provides a simple way to submit forms. ajax-form works with traditional form elements, as well as any custom elements that have both a name attribute and a value – including the Core and Paper input elements.

https://github.com/rnicholus/ajax-form
http://ajax-form.raynicholus.com

Answer (score 0):

Since, as you pointed out, `paper-button`s do not extend the native `button` element, you will have to either [write your own](http://jsbin.com/kurelaji/2/edit) JavaScript to handle form submission or wait for the [upcoming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867107/paper-button-with-type-submit-within-form-doesnt-submit#comment-38629349) `paper-forms` Polymer element.